# how can i simulate with arima.sim drift, intercept and trend

Tags: arima, simulation, trend

I am using arima.sim to simulate data. I want to introduce in the simulation intercept constant drift and trend and i dont know how do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Deterministic Trend

If your drift intercept is $c$, you can just add the function $c t$ to the zero mean process.

Code:

```
xt <- arima.sim(n=50, list(order=c(1,0,1), ar = c(.9), ma = -.2))
```

becomes

```
xtWithDrift <- xt + .20*seq(1,50))
```

The model would be written like
\begin{align*}
X_t &= \phi X_{t-1} + Z_t + \theta Z_{t-1} \\
Y_t &= a + ct + X_t.
\end{align*}

### Stochastic Trend

If you want a stochastic trend, you're better off simulating the differences, then summing those. With a nonrandom starting point, for example:

```
startSpot <- 3
yt <- arima.sim(n=50, list(order=c(1,0,1),ar=c(.9), ma=-.2)) + .2 #see comment below
plot(startSpot + cumsum(yt))
```

This gives you
$$
X_t = 3 + \sum_{j=1}^t Y_t
$$
where $Y_t$ is the ARMA(1,1). $X_t$ is the ARIMA(1,1,1). Or in other words, 
$$
(1 - \phi B)(Y_t - .2) = (1 + \theta B) Z_t,
$$
where $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the mean = 0.2 isn't doing exactly what you think it is. If you wish the $Y_t$ series to have a mean of approx 0.2 then add do yt <- arima.sim(...) + 0.2, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294748/arima-sim-again-what-does-the-mean-parameter-do-in-an-ma1-sim/

Comment: @markstep thanks very much. I just made the appropriate changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im trying to learn and i have a new question. I run like you write:
 
yt<-arima.sim(n=5000,list(order=c(1,0,0),ar=.9))+.2

then i run:

mean(yt)
(p<-arima(yt,order = c(1,0,0),include.mean = TRUE))  #Model Ar(1)

and i obtain
mean=0.181 
always a diferent value in several simulation and the coeficients ar(1)=0.9 always, what is right but the intercept is always the means,

With this model, the mean shouldnt be lamdba/(1-.9)=.2/.1=2??

Why this happen

Thank you again

Comment: @CarlosSergioJara no you're okay. .2 is the mean. The sample means should be close to .2 (.18 is pretty close). Your formula is correct about the intercept here, but it has nothing to do with this example. Maybe try simulating more examples, and calculate more sample means. You can also get a good idea of how far off it should be if you don't add .2. Calculate the sample means then, and see how close they are to 0

Comment: Thank You again ¿And when the mean in a process ar(1) would be lamba/(1-phi1)=2? ¿How could i simulate this process?

Being more precisely ¿What is mu=lambda/(1-phi) 
                                                20=.02/(1-.09)?

Comment: @CarlosSergioJara that's the intercept. that would be if you wrote it like $x_t = 2 + .9 x_{t-1} + z_t$. The way I wrote it is $x_t - .2 = .9(x_{t-1} - .2) + z_t$

Comment: Thank you again
I have problems to understand this parts ¿Have you any paper or file to read about this subjects (specificaction with mean and intercept and relation betwen them?

Comment: If you write $$x_{t}=0.2+.9x_{t−1}+z_{t}$$, the value 0.2 is the intercept (constant)  and when you write the model in difference you must write
$$(x_{t}−2)=.9(x_{t−1}−2)+z_{t}$$ where value 2 is the mean
and $$lambda=mu*(1-\phi_1)$$
¿Am i right?

Comment: @CarlosSergioJara yep that's right